# How to load localized JSON asset in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, localization

I have a localized Android Flutter app. I configured localization following these [instructions](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization). This works (although it feels unnecessarily complicated), and I am able to use localized strings throughout the app, but I cannot figure out how to load a localized asset JSON file.

I tried to store asset path as a localized string. But when I try to load the path from statefull widget's `initState` I get an error.

```
@override
void initState() {
    var t = AppLocalizations.of(context);
    await rootBundle.load(t!.localizedJsonPath);
    super.initState();
}
```

> FlutterError (dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_LocalizationsScope>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _MyScreenState.initState() completed.

Note that above approach works fine if I hard code the JSON asset file path. It only fails when I try to load  the localized string.

What am I doing wrong?

If there is a better way to load localized assets I will accept that as an answer. Flutter documentation mentions [asset variants](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#asset-variants) for image resolution and themes, but I could not find anything for localization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting appears to be with your context.

```
var t = AppLocalizations.of(context);
```

is called inside initState. However, your init state is called before your widget has a context, because it didn't build yet. So what you can try to do is use `didChangeDependencies()` instead of initState, like that:

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
        var t = AppLocalizations.of(context);
        await rootBundle.load(t!.localizedJsonPath);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

and one more thing: init state is not async, so try to`await` the methods you call does not really work.
keep me updated if your problem still persist!

Comment: is didChangeDependencies async? Is that a problem?

Comment: Also no. But not really a problem, because you have a solution. I suggest you to take a look at [this](https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-futurebuilder-383b6ed63f18)